# How to debug broken Git repository

Tags: git

I have a Git repository that has been working fine, until all of a sudden:

```
$ git status
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

The .git directory and all the files are still there:

```
$ ls -l .git
total 48
drwxr-xr-x  2 nikratio nikratio     2 Jan 16  2016 branches/
-rw-rw-r--  1 nikratio nikratio   612 Jan 19 10:17 COMMIT_EDITMSG
-rw-rw-r--  1 nikratio nikratio   553 Nov 24  2019 config
-rw-r--r--  1 nikratio nikratio    73 Jan 16  2016 description
-rw-r--r--  1 nikratio nikratio   188 Feb 28 09:41 FETCH_HEAD
-rw-r--r--  1 nikratio nikratio 11876 Mar  7  2016 gitk.cache
-rw-rw-r--  1 nikratio nikratio    23 Feb 28 09:41 HEAD
drwxr-xr-x  2 nikratio nikratio    11 Jan 16  2016 hooks/
-rw-rw-r--  1 nikratio nikratio  2764 Feb 28 09:41 index
drwxr-xr-x  2 nikratio nikratio     4 Feb  1  2020 info/
drwxr-xr-x  3 nikratio nikratio     4 Feb  1  2020 logs/
drwxr-xr-x 41 nikratio nikratio    41 Feb 28 09:41 objects/
-rw-rw-r--  1 nikratio nikratio    41 Feb 28 09:41 ORIG_HEAD
-rw-rw-r--  1 nikratio nikratio  3321 Feb  1  2020 packed-refs
drwxr-xr-x  5 nikratio nikratio     5 Aug  6  2017 refs/
drwxrwxr-x  2 nikratio nikratio     5 Nov  3  2019 sequencer/

$ cat .git/HEAD
dfd4cba3856cea89037f1e8⏎
```

How can I find out the extent of the damage, and what exactly has been corrupted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This data doesn't look right:

```
$ cat .git/HEAD
dfd4cba3856cea89037f1e8⏎
```

'HEAD' is a pointer to the currently checked-out commit. If you've checked out a branch tip, this file should contain `ref: refs/heads/master` (e.g. for the "master" branch). You can update it with `echo`.

(If you've checked out a non-tip commit, or a tag, then HEAD will directly contain that commit's hexadecimal hash – however, it would be exactly 40 digits for the SHA1 repositories currently in use. Yours *looks* like it was supposed to be a commit hash, but is too short.)

The ref name following "ref:" also needs to exist either as an actual file (`.git/refs/heads/master` in this example), always containing a 40-digit commit hash, or as a line in `.git/packed-refs`.

After you've fixed .git/HEAD, be sure to run `git fsck` to verify the repository's remaining contents. I suspect that there might be more files corrupted in the objects directory.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to fix .git/HEAD to get git to recognize the repository again. Unfortunately, git fsck then found a bunch of other errors so I'm declaring this a lost case.